# Should I avoid getting any pot in Poison or try to pick a color and get as much as possible?

Tags: untagged

What is the better strategy in Poison ([BGG](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/17025/poison))? Trying to get nothing at all may be a good strategy, but sometimes hard. Is it better to try to get the most of a color, so that this color doesn't count for you? Avoiding the poison, without a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I certainly favor taking a color. With good players it's impossible to get nothing, and if you pick a single color you'll have some control.

Once you start specializing in a color other players are unlikely to take any of that color if they can help it, ensuring you'll get the majority.

Once you have that solid majority, towards the last half or third of the game, you can foist pots of that color onto other players, knowing they'll be stuck with points. This gives you power that you don't have if you take nothing.

Of course, everyone else is trying to do the same thing. :)